# How to Save and search content (made with wysiwyg html editor) in mysql database?

Tags: html, mysql, laravel-4, wysiwyg, richtext

I want to use a wysiwyg html editor (like [this](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)) and save it to my mysql database.
What is the best way to store the content (I guess that in a Text type field all html code)?

so then you can search content. (Like:blogs,taringa,stackoberflow....)

If you store html code in the database, how can you do the query so it only search text content and not html tags?

Note:I have a Laravel 4 project. (preference using Eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

So now you're getting into search engine type of searching. You can go for DB simplicity or performance based searching. This answer will assume you have space to spare and you're not trying to condense as much space as possible.

DB Simplicity:

For this method you can really just throw the text (sanitized) into the DB and upon getting it back out you can print it with no sanitation {{{ $txt }}}. As for searching you just do a full text search on the entirety of the column for whatever you're searching for "%query%". You'll need to look into some raw querying as you can optimize it a bit.

Performance:

Upon entry you have two editions of the text which can help with printing and searching. Since you don't care about tags just have all of those stripped out (a rough regex would just delete anything in between angle brackets and the brackets themselves replace("<*>",""))

Might as well also remove punctuation as that can mess around with searching (your, you're). After you sanitize your text for search optimization you can then just have the printable column and do your searches on the search column. It'll still be slow as you're doing full-text searching but faster than also having to deal with tags.

Another strategy is to have yet another column as a unique word column, these usually can be called *tags*. So in this case you can also pull your data through another filter from the previous search-text and drop all the common words that don't have much meaning to them (the, or, by, it, is). You now probably have a list of semi related words to the article that possibly have duplicates, merge the duplicates with a count and order them from greatest to least in another column.

You now have multiple granularities of search depending on what you're goal is. You can also have this be enhanced with fuzzy searching, which does increase your search time and you'll probably have to create specific index tables to help decrease time spent searching.